# If date is leap day (29-Feb) change to 28-Feb

Tags: python, pandas

In a Pandas dataframe i need to change all leap days cells in a specific column (they should be changed to 28 Feb). So, for example, 2020/02/29 should become 2020/02/28.

I tried the following, but didn't work:

```
df.loc[((df['Date'].dt.month == 2) & (df['Date'].dt.day == 29)), 'Date'] = df['Date'] + timedelta-(1)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df["Date"] = np.where((df["Date"].dt.month == 2) & \
                      (df["Date"].dt.day == 29),
                      df["Date"] - pd.DateOffset(days=1),
                      df["Date"])
```

If you look closely, you have written `+ timedelta-(1)` which returns an error.  Using your method works fine if you instead write `+ timedelta(-1)`.